# Why aren't the messages and photos appearing on screen?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a very simple visual novel with a game world in a 3-by-3 grid,that the user can interact through text . My problem is that the messages and the pictures that were supposed to show aren't showing even though i have everything in the same file and the the first image appears broken ... What am i doing wrong ??

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The Forest of Lyrica </title>
<img src="" width="300" height="267">
<p id="output"></p>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your action...">
<button>enter</button>

<script>
  //Create the map
  var map = [];
  map[0] = "An old stone keep.";
  map[1] = "A deep well.";
  map[2] = "A sunny glade.";
  map[3] = "A sleeping dragon.";
  map[4] = "A narrow pathway.";
  map[5] = "An ancient gate.";
  map[6] = "The edge of a river.";
  map[7] = "A lonely wooden bench.";
  map[8] = "An isolated cottage. Faint music comes from inside.";

  //Help Menu
  var helpMessages = [];
  helpMessages[0] = "";
  helpMessages[1] = "I wonder if you could 'use' something to find out how deep the well is?";
  helpMessages[2] = "";
  helpMessages[3] = "Maybe if you had a sword, you could slay the dragon?";
  helpMessages[4] = "";
  helpMessages[5] = "";
  helpMessages[6] = "";
  helpMessages[7] = "";
  helpMessages[8] = "This seems like a nice place for music.";

  //Set the player's start location
  var mapLocation = 4;

  //Set the images
  var images = [];
  images[0] = "keep.jpg";
  images[1] = "well.jpg";
  images[2] = "glade.jpg";
  images[3] = "dragon.jpg";
  images[4] = "path.jpg";
  images[5] = "gate.jpg";
  images[6] = "river.jpg";
  images[7] = "bench.jpg";
  images[8] = "cottage.jpg";

  //Set the blocked-path messages
  var blockedPathMessages = [];
  blockedPathMessages[0] = "It's too dangerous to move that way.";
  blockedPathMessages[1] = "A mysterious force holds you back.";
  blockedPathMessages[2] = "A tangle of thorns blocks your way.";
  blockedPathMessages[3] = "You can't step over the dragon.";
  blockedPathMessages[4] = "";
  blockedPathMessages[5] = "The gate locks shut.";
  blockedPathMessages[6] = "The river is too deep to cross.";
  blockedPathMessages[7] = "The trees are too thick to pass.";
  blockedPathMessages[8] = "You're too scared to go that way.";

  //Create the items and set their locations
  var items = ["flute", "stone", "sword"];
  var itemLocations = [1, 6, 8];

  //An array to store what the player is carrying
  var backpack = [];

  //Initialize the player's input
  var playersInput = "";

  //Initialize the gameMessage
  var gameMessage = "";

  //Create an array of actions the game understands
  //and a variable to store the current action
  var actionsIKnow = ["north", "east", "south", "west", "take", "use", "drop"];
  var action = "";

  //An array of items the game understands
  //and a variable to store the current item
  var itemsIKnow = ["flute", "stone", "sword"];
  var item = "";

  //The img element
  var image = document.querySelector("img");

  //The input and output fields
  var output = document.querySelector("#output");
  var input = document.querySelector("#input");

  //The button
  var button = document.querySelector("button");
  button.style.cursor = "pointer";
  button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

  //Listen for enter key presses
  window.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);

  function keydownHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      clickHandler();
    }
  }

  //Display the player's location
  render();

  function clickHandler() {
    playGame();
  }

  function playGame() {

    //Get the player's input and convert it to lowercase
    playersInput = input.value;
    playersInput = playersInput.toLowerCase();

    //Reset these variables from the previous turn
    gameMessage = "";
    action = "";

    //Figure out the player's action
    for (i = 0; i < actionsIKnow.length; i++) {
      if (playersInput.indexOf(actionsIKnow[i]) !== −1) {
        action = actionsIKnow[i];
        console.log("player's action: " + action);
        break;
      }
    }

    //Figure out the item the player wants
    for (i = 0; i < itemsIKnow.length; i++) {
      if (playersInput.indexOf(itemsIKnow[i]) !== −1) {
        item = itemsIKnow[i];
        console.log("player's item: " + item);
      }
    }

    //Choose the correct action
    switch (action) {
      case "north":
        if (mapLocation >= 3) {
          mapLocation -= 3;
        } else {
          gameMessage = blockedPathMessages[mapLocation];
        }
        break;
      case "east":
        if (mapLocation % 3 != 2) {
          mapLocation += 1;
        } else {
          gameMessage = blockedPathMessages[mapLocation];
        }
        break;
      case "south":
        if (mapLocation < 6) {
          mapLocation += 3;
        } else {
          gameMessage = blockedPathMessages[mapLocation];
        }
        break;
      case "west":
        if (mapLocation % 3 != 0) {
          mapLocation -= 1;
        } else {
          gameMessage = blockedPathMessages[mapLocation];
        }
        break;
      case "take":
        takeItem()
        break;
      case "drop":
        dropItem();
        break;
      case "use":
        useItem();
        break;
      case "help":
        //Display a hint if there is one for this location
        if (helpMessages[mapLocation] !== "") {
          gameMessage = helpMessages[mapLocation] + " ";
        }
        gameMessage += "Try any of these words: "
        gameMessage += "north, east, south, west, take, drop, ";
        gameMessage += "use, stone, flute, sword.";
        break;
      default:
        gameMessage = "I don't understand that.";
    }

    //Render the game
    render();
  }

  function takeItem() {

    //Find the index number of the item in the items array
    var itemIndexNumber = items.indexOf(item);

    //Does the item exist in the game world and is it at the player's current location?
    if (itemIndexNumber !== −1 && itemLocations[itemIndexNumber] === mapLocation) {

      gameMessage = "You take the " + item + ".";
      //Add the item to the player's backpack
      backpack.push(item);
      //Remove the item from the game world
      items.splice(itemIndexNumber, 1);
      itemLocations.splice(itemIndexNumber, 1);
      //Display in the console for testing
      console.log("World items: " + items);
      console.log("backpack items: " + backpack);
    } else {
      //Message if the player tries to take an item that isn't in the current location
      gameMessage = "You can't do that.";
    }
  }

  function dropItem() {

    //Try to drop the item only if the backpack isn't empty
    if (backpack.length !== 0) {

      //Find the item's array index number in the backpack
      var backpackIndexNumber = backpack.indexOf(item);

      //The item is in the backpack if the backpackIndexNumber isn't −1
      if (backpackIndexNumber !== −1) {

        //Tell the player that the item has been dropped
        gameMessage = "You drop the " + item + ".";

        //Add the item from the backpack to the game world
        items.push(backpack[backpackIndexNumber]);
        itemLocations.push(mapLocation);

        //Remove the item from the player's backpack
        backpack.splice(backpackIndexNumber, 1);
      } else {
        //Message if the player tries to drop something that's not in the backpack
        gameMessage = "You can't do that.";
      }
    } else {
      //Message if the backpack is empty
      gameMessage = "You're not carrying anything.";
    }
  }

  function useItem() {
    //1. Find out if the item is in the backpack
    //Find the item's array index number in the backpack
    var backpackIndexNumber = backpack.indexOf(item);

    //If the index number is −1, then it isn't in the backpack.
    //Tell the player that he or she isn't carrying it.
    if (backpackIndexNumber === −1) {
      gameMessage = "You're not carrying it.";
    }

    //If there are no items in the backpack, then
    //tell the player the backpack is empty
    if (backpack.length === 0) {
      gameMessage += " Your backpack is empty";
    }
    //2. If the item is found in the backpack
    //figure out what to do with it
    if (backpackIndexNumber !== −1) {
      switch (item) {
        case "flute":
          if (mapLocation === 8) {
            gameMessage = "Beautiful music fills the air.";
            gameMessage += "A wizend old man steps outside "
            gameMessage += "and hands you a sword!";
            //Add the sword to the world
            items.push("sword");
            itemLocations.push(mapLocation);
          } else {
            gameMessage = "You try and play the flute "
            gameMessage += "but it makes no sound here.";
          }
          break;
        case "sword":
          if (mapLocation === 3) {
            gameMessage = "You swing the sword and slay the dragon! ";
            gameMessage += "You've saved the forest of Lyrica!";
          } else {
            gameMessage = "You swing the sword listlessly.";
          }
          break;
        case "stone":
          if (mapLocation === 1) {

            gameMessage = "You drop the stone in the well.";
            gameMessage += " A magical flute appears!";

            //Remove the stone from the player's backpack
            backpack.splice(backpackIndexNumber, 1);

            //Add the flute to the world
            items.push("flute");
            itemLocations.push(mapLocation);

            //Reset the location's help message
            helpMessages[mapLocation] = "";
          } else {
            gameMessage = "You fumble with the stone in your pocket.";
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  function render() {

    //Render the location
    output.innerHTML = map[mapLocation];
    image.src = images[mapLocation];

    //Display an item if there's one in this location
    //1. Loop through all the game items
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      //Find out if there's an item at this location
      if (mapLocation === itemLocations[i]) {
        //Display it
        output.innerHTML += "<br>You see a <strong>" +
          items[i] +
          "</strong> here.";
      }
    }
    //Display the game message
    output.innerHTML += "<br> <em>" + gameMessage + "</em>";

    //Display the player's backpack contents
    if (backpack.length !== 0) {
      output.innerHTML += "<br>You are carrying: " + backpack.join(", ");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code you want us to debug for you based on a fairly vague description.  Though the first thing one can't help but notice is the syntax error when you execute the code snippet right here on this page.

Comment: Can you retrace your steps and give us a more specific idea of where the error may reside? Surely there was a point where it stopped working between starting to code this and where it is currently.

Comment: The markup is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copyed your code and run it on chrome. After seeing the errors in the js console (Use It!) i noticed you used the wrong "-" sign

```
−1 instead of -1
```

after changing this your code ran just fine for me

Comment: Thank you so much !!Yeah i will definitely use it from now on !! :)